# SVN propset svn:needs-lock on local directory

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to set the svn:needs-lock property on a local directory, and then to commit it. I want to do it from the command line and it seems to not letting me.

my command is:

```
svn propset svn:needs-lock '*' d:\src_svn\Multilizer
```

the answer I get is:

```
svn: Cannot set 'svn:needs-lock' on a directory ('D:\src_svn\Multilizer')
```

what can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `needs-lock` can't be applied on a directory:

> If present on a file, tells the client to make the file read-only in the working copy, as a reminder that the file should be locked before editing begins. See the section called “Lock Communication”.

More in the SVN book: [Lock Communication](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.locking.html#svn.advanced.locking.lock-communication)